# how to install plugins to ckeditor5 in laravel

Tags: laravel, ckeditor5, ckeditor-plugin

After installing the SourceEditing plugin according to [the site](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/source-editing.html), it gives this error Uncaught ReferenceError: SourceEditing is not defined

```
  .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
               
                plugins: [ SourceEditing],
})
```

Import is also done.